ResNet50 CNN model won't fit
Below is my code for a CNN using ResNet50, I have used it in the past however, I recently changed the structure of the input to the model and I seem to get the following error below. I also printed the shape of my image array which you can see below train_inputs.shape =  (4727, 224, 224, 3). And len(train_labels) = 4727.
Also the error seems to be occurring at the following block of code:
history = model.fit(train_inputs_resized, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint])

Error Message:
Packages Loaded                                                                                                                             
main started                                                                                                                    
(4727, 6, 100, 100)                                                                                                                                         
4727                                                                                            
images collected                                                                                                                                
(4727, 6, 224, 224)                                                                                                                                         
(4727, 6, 224, 224)                                                                                                                                         
(4727, 6, 224, 224, 3)                                                                                                                                       
(4727, 224, 224, 3)                                                                                                                                         
model loaded                                                                                                                    
model built                                                                                                                 
(4727, 224, 224, 3)                                                                                                                                         
4727                                                                                            
Epoch 1/10                                                                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                           
  File "/oscar/scratch/aagudel1/SenID/Code/CNN_RN503D.py", line 388, in <module>                                                                             
    main()                                                                                                              
  File "/oscar/scratch/aagudel1/SenID/Code/CNN_RN503D.py", line 352, in main                                                                                 
    history = model.fit(train_inputs_resized, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_siz                                                                             e=32, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint])                                                                                    
  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/trac                                                                             eback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler                                                                                                                  
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None                                                                                                            
  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ea                                                                             ger/execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute                                                                                                                   
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,                                                                                   
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution er                                                                             ror:                                                                                            

Detected at node LogicalAnd defined at (most recent call last):
  File "/oscar/scratch/aagudel1/SenID/Code/CNN_RN503D.py", line 388, in <module>

  File "/oscar/scratch/aagudel1/SenID/Code/CNN_RN503D.py", line 352, in main

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 325, in fit

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 118, in one_step_on_iterator

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 106, in one_step_on_data

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 77, in train_step

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/trainers/trainer.py", line 376, in compute_metrics

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/traineompile_utils.py", line 330, in update_state

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/trompile_utils.py", line 17, in update_state

  File "/users/aagudel1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/bansorflow/numpy.py", line 1194, in logical_and

Incompatible shapes: [1,64] vs. [1,32]
         [[{{node LogicalAnd}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_12

Full Code of the Main Function:
def main():
"""
This script performs the following tasks:
1. Collects and processes images of cycling and senescent cells.
2. Splits the data into training and testing sets.
3. Loads a pre-trained ResNet50 model and adds custom layers.
4. Trains the model using the processed images.
5. Evaluates the model's performance on the test set.
6. Generates a confusion matrix and classification report.
7. Visualizes the results, including correctly and incorrectly classified examples.
"""
print("main started")
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
output_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, "../Data/")
out1_dir = os.path.join(output_dir, "/users/aagudel1/scratch/SenID/Images/SegmentedImages/Prolif/")
out2_dir = os.path.join(output_dir, "/users/aagudel1/scratch/SenID/Images/SegmentedImages/Senescent/")
train_inputs, test_inputs, train_labels, test_labels = collect_images(out1_dir, out2_dir, train_ratio=0.8, random_state=42)
print(train_inputs.shape)
print(len(train_labels))
print("images collected")
# Assuming images are already 3D
train_inputs = ImageCropper.crop_images(train_inputs)
print(train_inputs.shape)
test_inputs = ImageCropper.crop_images(test_inputs)
train_inputs = preprocess_input(train_inputs)
test_inputs = preprocess_input(test_inputs)
print(train_inputs.shape)
train_inputs_resized = np.repeat(train_inputs[..., np.newaxis], 3, axis=-1)
print(train_inputs_resized.shape)
test_inputs_resized = np.repeat(test_inputs[..., np.newaxis], 3, axis=-1)
# Combine slices using Maximum Intensity Projection (MIP)
train_inputs_resized = np.max(train_inputs_resized, axis=1)
print(train_inputs_resized.shape)
test_inputs_resized = np.max(test_inputs_resized, axis=1)
# Load ResNet50 as a base model and add custom layers
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)



print("model loaded")
# Unfreeze the last few layers
for layer in base_model.layers[:-5]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in base_model.layers[-5:]:
    layer.trainable = True

# Add custom layers
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(x)

# Build the final model
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
print("model built")
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', Precision(), Recall()])

# Early stopping and model checkpoints
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.keras', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)

# Train the model
print(train_inputs_resized.shape)
print(len(train_labels))
history = model.fit(train_inputs_resized, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint])
plot_history(history, "model_loss.png")
print("model trained")
#tf.print("Value of output tensor:", output)

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_inputs_resized, test_labels)

print(f"Test accuracy: {test_acc}")
print(f"Test loss: {test_loss}")

y_pred = model.predict(test_inputs_resized)
y_pred_binary = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
class_labels = ["Cycling", "Senescene"]
create_confusion_matrix(test_labels, y_pred_binary, class_labels, "confusion_matrix.png")

print(classification_report(test_labels, y_pred_binary))
accuracy = accuracy_score(test_labels, y_pred_binary)
print("Test Accuracy", accuracy.round(4) * 100)
precision = precision_score(test_labels, y_pred_binary)
print("Test Precision", precision.round(4) * 100)
recall = recall_score(test_labels, y_pred_binary)
print("Test Recall", recall.round(4) * 100)
f1 = f1_score(test_labels, y_pred_binary)
print("Test F1", f1.round(4) * 100)

test_inputs = (test_inputs_resized - test_inputs_resized.min()) / (test_inputs_resized.max() - test_inputs_resized.min())

visualize_results(
    image_inputs=test_inputs_resized,
    probabilities=y_pred,
    image_labels=test_labels,
    first_label="Cycling",
    second_label="Senescene")

Any ideas on how to fix this or trouble shoot? The error message says incompatible shapes [1,64] vs. [1,32] but I have no idea what shapes it could be referring to

I'm not familiar enough with tensorflow to give a useful answer, but as you are referencing 32 in one place, have you tried setting the training batch size to 64?

Nice catch however, changing the batch size to 64 give the following error:
Incompatible shapes: [1,128] vs. [1,64]
[[{{node LogicalAnd}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_12722]

If you only have 2 classes, it's way better to use
loss = 'binary_crossentropy' in compile, and
Dense(1, active='sigmoid', ...) as the output layer.

It seems like  I forgot to convert my labels to categorical data this seem to fix this issue.
